# Is it possible to create dynamic function in PHP5

Tags: php, class, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I have a script i use to extend for my database object, what i went is build a little more complex class to save code over all so i will ask you guys here on this site about sombordy know a way to build it.

First i got this code

**Abstract class**

```
abstract class dbObjExtend {
// empty for now
}
```

**Normal controller class**

```
class obj extends dbObjExtend {
    public function setVar1($value) {
        $this->_var1 = $value;
    }

    public function setVar2($value) {
        $this->_var2 = $value;
    }

    public function setVar3($value) {
        $this->_var3 = $value;
    }

    public function setVar3($value) {
        $this->_var3 = $value;
    }
}
```

what i want now is move my setVar function inside the dbObjExtend dynamic so i can call and build new "set functions" when i need it, i hope you understand my question my abstract class will look like this if its possible.

**Abstract class**

```
abstract class dbObjExtend {
    public function setVar($key, $value) {
        $this->_{$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

if its possible to do this way i will make it easyer to call my functions on this way

**Normal controller class - after**

```
class obj extends dbObjExtend {
    public hello() {
        echo "Var1: ". $this->_var1 ."\n";
        echo "Var3: ". $this->_var2 ."\n";
        echo "Var3: ". $this->_var3 ."\n";
    }
}
```

**Sample code**

```
$obj = new obj;
$obj->setVar('var1', $value1);
$obj->setVar('var2', $value2);
$obj->setVar('var2', $value3);
```

Thanks for your time, and hope you understand what my point is :)

Comment: Why not just use [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)? `__get()`, `__set()`, `__isset()`?

Comment: its it possible to create protected, private and public dynamic with magic methods?

Comment: Why don't you read about it at the link I provided?

Comment: Besides the suggestion to use magic methods, didnt you just answer your own question? The code you wrote seems to be valid (have not tested it). Or are you asking for something else as well, in that case, I did not understand your question

Comment: Yes i don't know what i'm thinking on last day, sorry i awser my self about what i want :) sorry for you time guys